# Conditional count in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user_login` with two rows, userId and tstamp (user id and timestamp of login).

Counting the number of logins is simple:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*) as logins FROM user_login GROUP BY userId;
```

Counting the number of logins before a certain date (e.g. Jan 1 2018) is also simple:

```
SELECT userId
     , COUNT(*) as loginsBeforeJan1 
  FROM user_login 
 WHERE tstamp < '2018-01-01' 
 GROUP 
    BY userId;
```

How can I have both results in one table? I tried

```
SELECT userId
     , COUNT(*) as logins
     , COUNT(IF(tstamp < '2018-01-01',1,0)) loginsBeforeJan1 
  FROM user_login 
 GROUP 
    BY userId;
```

but both the logins and loginsBeforeJan1 are identical.

How can I modify the query to produce the result I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a sum  (and group by)

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*) as logins, sum(IF(tstamp < '2018-01-01',1,0)) as loginsBeforeJan1 
FROM user_login
group by userId;
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add the GROUP BY! I'll edit my question

Comment: Ok  .. for group by but you should use sum and not count

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `WHERE` clause instead of the `IF` statement in your query